# CPU Load is 100% non-stop after installing 500 new fonts

Tags: 13.10, fonts, bug-reporting, cpu-load, ubuntu-font-family

Since I installed 500 new fonts and cleaned data with BleachBit, My CPU loading is 100% non-stop every time I turn on my laptop or restart it.

After waiting few time in power off, I switched it on and it runs normally. What's the problem?

Comment: Run the system monitor and note the high CPU process. Add it to your question.

Answer (score 1):

It's an unsolved bug related to `dbus-deamon`.The only known solutions are either killing the software that started the bug or few restarts.
I have written about it [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/410993/184942), but it went unnoticed.

Comment: Can bug in dbus-daemon solved in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS?

Comment: there is little chance that someone would solve this bug.the reasons are 1.old and has gone mostly unnoticed 2.affects very little people 3.is not permanent 4.has very little or no damage potential 5.can be easily fixed.

Comment: Oh? Thanks for info. Hope this can be fixed in next LTS or non-LTS version.